# The concept behind how hashes are combined in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, math, hash

I came across the `combine_hash_arrays` functions in pandas library [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/util/hashing.py). How does it keep good collision rate after combination ? Does anyone have the mathematical proof for this code ?

The below code is retrieved from pandas implementation.

```
def combine_hash_arrays(
    arrays: Iterator[np.ndarray], num_items: int
) -> npt.NDArray[np.uint64]:
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    arrays : Iterator[np.ndarray]
    num_items : int

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray[uint64]

    Should be the same as CPython's tupleobject.c
    """
    try:
        first = next(arrays)
    except StopIteration:
        return np.array([], dtype=np.uint64)

    arrays = itertools.chain([first], arrays)

    mult = np.uint64(1000003)
    out = np.zeros_like(first) + np.uint64(0x345678)
    last_i = 0
    for i, a in enumerate(arrays):
        inverse_i = num_items - i
        out ^= a
        out *= mult
        mult += np.uint64(82520 + inverse_i + inverse_i)
        last_i = i
    assert last_i + 1 == num_items, "Fed in wrong num_items"
    out += np.uint64(97531)
    return out
```

I have already checked whether they work well by checking their combined hashes' collision rate.